# Identifying Sharepoint List column names

Tags: python, sharepoint

Heres the code I am currently using:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/"
sp_list = "xxx"
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("xxx@xxx.xx", "xxx"))
sp_lists = ctx.web.lists
s_list = sp_lists.get_by_title(sp_list)
l_items = s_list.get_items()
ctx.load(l_items)
ctx.execute_query()

for item in l_items:
    print(item.properties["Title"], item.properties["xxx"])
```

The code itself work, but when I try to access data from other columns apart from Title it gives me KeyError.
The primary (Title) column name was modified, yet managed to get it from the url.

But I am having trouble with the rest of the columns' display name, mostly because they contain special characters. Tried to find the original names just like with Title from the url, sadly did not work.

Any idea how I could get the proper name of those columns that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by changing the last line of code from this:

```
for item in l_items:
    print(item.properties["Title"])
```

To this:

```
for item in l_items:
    print(item.properties)
```

This way I get all the data printed out with the proper name of the columns.